How to update values of a controlled pre-filled textfield on onBlur event in react formik
I'm trying to set bank name, address and branch based on IFSE details. For all these fields, formik Textboxes are used. On OnBlur event of IFSE textbox, all the other 3 should get populated i.e. bank name, branch and address.
Here is my code:
This I made a formik textbox template that I'm using in other forms too:
export const ReusableTextField = ({ label, name, value, type, error, helperText, onChange, ...rest }) => {
    const { touched, handleChange, values, setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();
    const isError = Boolean(error);
    const selectedValue = values[name] || '';

    useEffect(() => {
        setFieldValue(name, stateValue);
    }, [stateValue]);

    return (
        <FormControl variant="outlined" fullWidth error={isError}>
            <Field
                as={TextField}
                name={name}
                label={label}
                fullWidth
                type={type}
                value={values[name] || ''}
                onChange={(event) => {
                    handleChange(event);
                    if (onChange) {
                        onChange(name, event.target.value);
                    }
                }}
                {...rest}
            />
            {isError && touched[name] && <FormHelperText>{helperText}</FormHelperText>}
        </FormControl>
    );
};


This is my code here:
const BankDetails = ({ onNext, onBack }) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [studBankDetails, setStudBankDetails] = useState('');
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
    const [uploadedPassBook, setUploadedPassBook] = useState(null);
    const [tempPassBook, setTempPassBook] = useState(null);
    const [passBookURL, setPassBookURL] = useState('');

    const [studentAccNo, setStudentAccNo] = useState(null);
    const [studentBankIfse, setStudentBankIfse] = useState(null);
    const [studentBankName, setStudentBankName] = useState(null);
    const [studentBankBranch, setStudentBankBranch] = useState(null);
    const [studentBankAddress, setStudentBankAddress] = useState(null);

    const [getBankDetails, setGetBankDetails] = useState(null);

    const fileInputRef = useRef(null); // Create a reference to the file input
    const classes = useStyles();

    const token = useSelector((state) => state.userStore.token);

    const handleFormChange = (name, value) => {
        //
        //setRole_List((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value, key: selectedOption.key }));
        setStudBankDetails((prevValues) => ({
            ...prevValues,
            [name]: value
        }));
    };

   

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchBankDetails();
    }, []);

    const fetchBankDetails = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(serverIpAddress + '/api/v1/bank/get', {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            });
            console.log(response);
            setGetBankDetails(response.data.pd[0]);
            setIsLoading(false);
        } catch (err) {
            // Handle error
            console.log('Error fetching bank info:', err);
        }
    };

    const handleOnBlur = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;

        if (`${name}` == 'studIfsc') {
            const reg = {
                ifsc_code: `${value}`
            };
            //console.log(`${name} ${value} ${token}`, reg);
            axios
                .post(serverIpAddress + '/api/v1/bank/validateIFSC', reg, {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                    }
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data.pd);
                    setStudentBankName(response.data.pd.BANK);
                    setStudentBankBranch(response.data.pd.BRANCH);
                    setStudentBankAddress(response.data.pd.ADDRESS);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    // Handle deletion error
                    console.log('Error fetching ifse info:', err);
                });
        }
    };

    const handleBackClick = () => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const instructions = {
            // schoolName
        };
        setValue(value - 1);

        onBack(instructions, value - 1); // Show the table on button click
    };
  
    

    return (
        <div>
            {isLoading ? (
                <div className={classes.spinnerContainer}>
                    <CircularProgress color="primary" />
                </div>
            ) : (
                <div>
                    <Grid container direction="column" alignItems="center">
                        <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.formContainer}>
                            {' '}
                            {console.log('bank acc no:', getBankDetails.account_number)}
                            <Formik
                                initialValues={{
                                    /* initialValues */
                                    studAccNo: getBankDetails.account_number ? getBankDetails.account_number : '',
                                    studIfsc: getBankDetails.ifsc_code ? getBankDetails.ifsc_code : '',
                                    studBankName: getBankDetails.name ? getBankDetails.name : '',
                                    studBankBranch: getBankDetails.branch ? getBankDetails.branch : '',
                                    studBankAddress: getBankDetails.bank_address ? getBankDetails.bank_address : ''
                                }}
                                onSubmit={async (studBankDetails, { setErrors, setStatus, setSubmitting }) => {
                                    console.log('enter onsubmit');
                                    try {
                                        console.log('enter onsubmit try');
                                        console.log('JSON values:', JSON.stringify(studBankDetails, null, 2));
                                        // setStatus({ success: false });
                                        // setSubmitting(false);
                                        setIsLoading(true);
                                        postData(studBankDetails);
                                    } catch (err) {
                                        console.log('inside  catch');
                                        setStatus({ success: false });
                                        setErrors({ submit: err.message });
                                        // setSubmitting(false);
                                    }
                                }}
                            >
                                {({ errors, touched, studCountry, studState, handleChange, handleSubmit, isSubmitting }) => (
                                    <>
                                        <div>
                                            <Typography
                                                variant="h5"
                                                className={classes.typo}
                                                sx={{
                                                    pb: 5,
                                                    background: '#f7d9c4',
                                                    color: 'white',
                                                    height: '50px',
                                                    borderTopLeftRadius: '10px', // Rounded border on the top-left corner
                                                    borderTopRightRadius: '10px',
                                                    paddingTop: '10px' //
                                                }}
                                            >
                                                Bank Details
                                            </Typography>
                                            <br /> <br />
                                            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                                                <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                                                    <Stack spacing={1}>
                                                        {/*  <InputLabel>Account Number</InputLabel> */}
                                                        <ReusableTextField
                                                            required
                                                            variant="outlined"
                                                            type="number"
                                                            label="Account Number"
                                                            value={studBankDetails.studAccNo}
                                                            name="studAccNo"
                                                            onChange={handleFormChange}
                                                            error={errors.studAccNo}
                                                            //disabled={true}
                                                            //helperText="Account no. is required"
                                                        />
                                                    </Stack>
                                                </Grid>

                                                <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                                                    <Stack spacing={1}>
                                                        {/*  <InputLabel>IFSC Code</InputLabel> */}
                                                        <ReusableTextField
                                                            required
                                                            variant="outlined"
                                                            type="text"
                                                            label="IFSC code"
                                                            value={studBankDetails.studIfsc}
                                                            name="studIfsc"
                                                            onChange={handleFormChange}
                                                            error={errors.studIfsc}
                                                            onBlur={handleOnBlur}
                                                            //disabled={true}
                                                            //helperText="IFSC code is required"
                                                        />
                                                    </Stack>
                                                </Grid>
                                                {studentBankName ? studentBankName : 'null'}
                                                <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                                                    <Stack spacing={1}>
                                                        {/* <InputLabel>Name of the bank</InputLabel> */}

                                                        <ReusableTextField
                                                            required
                                                            variant="outlined"
                                                            type="text"
                                                            label="Name of the bank"
                                                            value={studentBankName}
                                                            name="studBankName"
                                                            onChange={handleFormChange}
                                                            //disabled={true}
                                                            //error={errors.studBankName}
                                                            //disabled={true}
                                                            //helperText="Bank Name is required"
                                                        />
                                                    </Stack>
                                                </Grid>

                                                <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                                                    <Stack spacing={1}>
                                                        {/*  <InputLabel>Bank Branch</InputLabel> */}
                                                        <ReusableTextField
                                                            required
                                                            variant="outlined"
                                                            type="text"
                                                            label="Bank Branch"
                                                            value={studentBankBranch || studBankDetails.studBankBranch}
                                                            name="studBankBranch"
                                                            onChange={handleFormChange}
                                                            //disabled={true}
                                                            /* error={errors.studBankBranch}
                                                            disabled={true} */
                                                            //helperText="Account no. is required"
                                                        />
                                                    </Stack>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                                                    <Stack spacing={1}>
                                                        {/*  <InputLabel>Bank Address</InputLabel> */}
                                                        <ReusableTextField
                                                            required
                                                            variant="outlined"
                                                            type="text"
                                                            label="Bank Address"
                                                            value={studentBankAddress || studBankDetails.studBankAddress}
                                                            name="studBankAddress"
                                                            onChange={handleFormChange}

                                                            //disabled={true}
                                                            /* error={errors.studBankBranch}
                                                            disabled={true} */
                                                            //helperText="Account no. is required"
                                                        />
                                                    </Stack>
                                                </Grid>

                                                {/* <Grid item xs={12} md={12}>
                                                <Stack spacing={1}>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <b>Profile photo upload instructions:</b>
                                                        <ul>
                                                            <p style={{ color: '#f17d27' }}>
                                                                The maximum allowable file size is <b>20kb</b> per upload. Acceptable file
                                                                formats:Images(PNG,JPEG OR JPG).
                                                            </p>
                                                            Click on <b>'Select file'</b> to select the image.
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </li>
                                                </Stack>
                                            </Grid>

                                            <Grid item xs={12} md={12}>
                                                <input
                                                    accept="image/*"
                                                    className={classes.input}
                                                    id="file-upload"
                                                    type="file"
                                                    onChange={handleFileChange}
                                                />

                                                <label htmlFor="file-upload" className={classes.label}>
                                                    <Button
                                                        variant="outlined"
                                                        color="primary"
                                                        component="span"
                                                        className={classes.selectButton}
                                                        sx={{
                                                            backgroundColor: '#dd732c',
                                                            color: 'white',
                                                            '&:hover': {
                                                                backgroundColor: '#db6f04'
                                                            }
                                                        }}
                                                    >
                                                        Select File
                                                    </Button>
                                                    <Typography variant="body1">
                                                        {selectedFile ? `Selected file: ${selectedFile.name}` : 'No file selected'}
                                                    </Typography>
                                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                    <Button
                                                        variant="outlined"
                                                        color="primary"
                                                        component="span"
                                                        className={classes.button}
                                                        onClick={() => handleUpload(handleUploadCallback)}
                                                        disabled={!selectedFile}
                                                        sx={{
                                                            backgroundColor: '#dd732c',
                                                            color: 'white',
                                                            '&:hover': {
                                                                backgroundColor: '#db6f04'
                                                            }
                                                        }}
                                                    >
                                                        Upload
                                                    </Button>
                                                </label>

                                                {isImageUploaded && documents.length > 0 && (
                                                    <div>
                                                        <br></br>
                                                        <img
                                                            src={documents[0].filepath}
                                                            alt={documents.filename}
                                                            style={{ height: '200px', width: '200px' }}
                                                        />
                                                        <IconButton onClick={() => handleDelete(documents[0].doc_id)}>
                                                            <DeleteIcon />
                                                        </IconButton>
                                                    </div>
                                                )}
                                            </Grid> */}
                                                <Grid item xs={12} md={12}>
                                                    <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                                                        <Stack spacing={1}>
                                                            <b>Upload bank identification document (Passbook/Cancelled Cheque)</b>
                                                            <TextField
                                                                type="file"
                                                                //label="Attach your Aadhar card"
                                                                inputProps={{
                                                                    accept: 'application/pdf, application/msword, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
                                                                }}
                                                                onChange={handlePassBookFileChange}
                                                                inputRef={fileInputRef} // Assign the reference to the file input
                                                                disabled={isPassBookDisabled}
                                                                InputProps={{
                                                                    endAdornment: (uploadedPassBook || isPassBookDisabled) && !passBook && (
                                                                        <InputAdornment position="end">
                                                                            <IconButton
                                                                                //onClick={handleAadharFileDelete(aadharDocument.doc_id)}
                                                                                onClick={handlePassBookFileDelete}
                                                                            >
                                                                                <DeleteIcon />
                                                                            </IconButton>
                                                                        </InputAdornment>
                                                                    )
                                                                }}
                                                            />
                                                            {passBook && (
                                                                <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                                                    <Link
                                                                        href={passBook.filepath}
                                                                        target="_blank"
                                                                        rel="noopener noreferrer"
                                                                        style={{ marginRight: '8px' }} // Adds space between the link and the icon
                                                                    >
                                                                        <Typography variant="body2">
                                                                            Passbook: {passBook.filename}
                                                                        </Typography>
                                                                    </Link>
                                                                    <IconButton onClick={() => handleDelete(passBook.doc_id)}>
                                                                        <DeleteIcon />
                                                                    </IconButton>
                                                                </div>
                                                            )}
                                                            {uploadedPassBook && (
                                                                <Link href={passBookURL} target="_blank" rel="noopener">
                                                                    {uploadedPassBook.name}
                                                                </Link>
                                                            )}
                                                        </Stack>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </Grid>

                                                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                                                    <Grid item xs={12}></Grid>
                                                    <br></br>
                                                    <br></br>

                                                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                                                        <Button
                                                            variant="contained"
                                                            color="primary"
                                                            sx={{
                                                                boxShadow: 7,
                                                                borderRadius: '75px',
                                                                background: 'linear-gradient(to right, #1890ff, #1890ff, #1890ff, #1890ff)'
                                                            }}
                                                            onClick={handleBackClick}
                                                        >
                                                            Back
                                                        </Button>
                                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                        <Button
                                                            variant="contained"
                                                            color="primary"
                                                            type="submit"
                                                            sx={{
                                                                boxShadow: 7,
                                                                borderRadius: '75px',
                                                                background: 'linear-gradient(to right, #1890ff, #1890ff, #1890ff, #1890ff)'
                                                                // 'linear-gradient(to top, #a94bb9, #9b46b7, #8d42b5, #7d3eb2, #6d3ab0)'
                                                                // width: '200px',
                                                                // height: '50px',
                                                                // display: 'flex',
                                                                // justifyContent: 'center',
                                                                // alignItems: 'center'
                                                            }}
                                                            // disabled={!isImageUploaded}
                                                        >
                                                            Save and continue
                                                        </Button>
                                                        {errorMessage && (
                                                            <Typography variant="body2" color="error">
                                                                {errorMessage}
                                                            </Typography>
                                                        )}
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </div>
                                    </>
                                )}
                            </Formik>
                            <br></br>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default BankDetails;


My bank name, branch and address is not getting set. Please help.

You have a fundamental misundertanding of Formik here, which is indicated by that you are managing the form state manually. ReusableTextField should never be passed a value prop. Its value is fetched from the Formik context based on the name prop. You can't/shouldn't be managing form values as useStates. You can set values inside the formik state by calling setFieldValue from useFormikContext. Though it is worth noting all the logic to do this will need to be inside a component that is a child of ,  as the aprent component does not have the context.

Apologies for my amateur attempt as I'm new to this language. Could you please guide me so as to attend the desired outcome?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
